# How to deconstruct complex C/C++ statements/declarations?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, declaration, pointer-to-pointer

Take the following snippet as an example.

```
char* const (*(* const bar)[5])(int)
```

Cannot seem to make sense of it or more so, cannot identify the initial point from where to begin making sense of it.

Comment: [https://cdecl.org/?q=char*+const+%28*%28*+const+bar%29%5B5%5D%29%28int%29](https://cdecl.org/?q=char*+const+%28*%28*+const+bar%29%5B5%5D%29%28int%29)

Comment: **There is no spiral rule.** The only rule is ‘declaration reflects use’.

Comment: @user3840170 can you elaborate ?

Comment: you easily put such a statement in chatgpt to get an explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the declaration step by steap

```
char* const (*(* const bar)[5])(int);
```

This part

```
* const bar
```

declares a constant pointer with the name `bar` that points to  to an array of 5 elements of a pointer type

```
*(* const bar)[5]
```

that is pointer to the function type

```
char* const (int)
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * const f1( int n )
{
    printf( "f1 called with n = %d\n", n );

    return NULL;
}

char *const f2( int n )
{
    printf( "f2 called with n = %d\n", n );

    return NULL;
}

char *const f3( int n )
{
    printf( "f3 called with n = %d\n", n );

    return NULL;
}

char *const f4( int n )
{
    printf( "f4 called with n = %d\n", n );

    return NULL;
}

char *const f5( int n )
{
    printf( "f5 called with n = %d\n", n );

    return NULL;
}

int main( void )
{
    char *const ( *a[5] )( int ) = { f1, f2, f3, f4, f5 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        a[i]( i );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    char *const ( *( *const bar )[5] )( int ) = &a;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        ( *bar )[i]( i );
    }

}
```

The program output is

```
f1 called with n = 0
f2 called with n = 1
f3 called with n = 2
f4 called with n = 3
f5 called with n = 4

f1 called with n = 0
f2 called with n = 1
f3 called with n = 2
f4 called with n = 3
f5 called with n = 4
```

Using typedef declarations could make the declaration of the pointer much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The "declaration reflect use" says that:
The expression `*(*(*bar)[0])(0)` gives a `char`.

We can continue saying:
The expression `(*(*bar)[0])(0)` gives a pointer to a `char`.

So:
Calling function `(*(*bar)[0])` with (int) parameter returns a pointer to a `char`.
...
**dereference `bar` then indexes in array (sized 5) to have a pointer on a function with (int) parameter will returns a pointer to a `char`**.

The expression can also be decoded starting with the object. Here we have the name `bar` as a start. But in some expressions we do not have any name, the start point is the first expression (in parentheses) that has at its right an array[...] or a function call(...) or nothing.
Note that to read an expression we 1st read part at right (arrays and functions), and finish reading 1st at left then other at left (pointers).

1. Seeing the start expression : `(* const bar)`, `bar` is constant pointer to...
   Replacing expression as `bbar`, we have `char* const (* bbar[5])(int);`
2. Seeing upper expression : `(* bbar[5])`, `bbar` is an array of 5 pointers to...
   Replacing expression as `bbbar`, we have `char* const bbbar(int);`
3. Seeing upper expression : `char* const bbbar(int)`, `bbbar` is a function receiving an `int` and returning a constant pointer to a `char`.

**`bar` is a constant pointer to an array of 5 pointers to functions receiving (`int`) returning constant pointer to `char`**.

In real we never have to do that, complex expressions are `typedef`:

```
typedef char* const (*  FunctionPtr)(int);
typedef FunctionPtr     ArrayOfFctPtr[5];
ArrayOfFctPtr* const    bar;
```